# how to shrink a very big log file in SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, database-administration, shrink, in-memory-tables

I have a warehouse with a 800 GB log file.now I want to shrink or another solution to reduce the disk space occupied by the Log.ldf.
I tried shrink file in several ways.I got a full backup , transaction log back up , changed recovery mode , ran dbcc command but none of them affected log file volume in disk , detach database and then deleted the log file but because of memory-optimize file container I faced error while I attempted to attach it again (I read SQL server will automatically add a log file but apparently  not when database has a memory_optimize file ) 
after all these solutions my log file is still 800 GB and I don't know what to do to free disk space used by log file.
Is there any suggestion ? Or do I forget to do sth in my approaches ?

Comment: 1: got a full backup and also transaction backup _
set recovery to simple _
checkpoint _
dbcc shrink file ___:     didn't work
2:detach __ , then delete log file__  attach with restore  ___:   didn't work!

Comment: post this on dba.stackexchange.com and i think you'll get some good feedback